# Can I add the search box to a template without xml?

Tags: magento2, template, search

Can I add the search box to a template without xml?

I need to create a dropdown with the search box when I click on a magnifying glass icon.

Comment: do you want to call search box in another phtml ?

Comment: Yes. I just created a custom search bar. I want to make it a dropdown from nav.

Comment: if you want search box you can call it by: <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml")->toHtml();?>

Comment: let me know if have any issue.

Comment: When I enter that into the phtml file the DOM states that its loading twice. It get a console error showing duplicate IDs for #search and #search_mini_form. Any idea what is causing that?

Comment: However, it does not appear twice in the elements section.

Comment: I fixed it. I removed search via xml and now the error is gone. Please move your response to the answer and I will select it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: great, I have convert comment to answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `search box` by following code in phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

Hope above will help!

**Update I**

If you want this search bar with default one you need to create copy of `form.mini.phtml` say `form.mini.custom.phtml`

from:

> Mage2Root/vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtml

to

> Mage2Root/app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Search/templates/form.mini.custom.phtml

change ids from `search_mini_form` to `search_mini_form_custom` and input id from `search` to `search.custom`

finally call this by:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Search::form.mini.custom.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```